# How to create a SQLite database with rust sqlx

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

I'm trying out a conversion from rusqlite => sqlx.

Opening a connection from `rusqlite` calls SQLite::open, and creates the db files. The following works:

```rs
use rusqlite::Connection;

Connection::open(db_filename)
```

However, I'm following the docs on the sqlx side (https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx#connecting), and they launch me immediately into creating a pool:

```
use sqlx::sqlite::{SqlitePoolOptions};

SqlitePoolOptions::new()
            .max_connections(1)
            .connect(&format!("sqlite://{}", db_filename))
            .await
            .map_err(|err| format!("{}\nfile: {}", err.to_string(), db_filename))?;
```

which in fact yields the `Result<_, String>` message of:

```
Error: "error returned from database: unable to open database file\nfile: /path/to/my.db"
```

I'm not clear how in the `sqlx` world to actually write those db files on first boot.

Tips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found an issue in their issue tracker, where you can use `?mode=rwc` query style param on the filename.

https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/issues/1114#issuecomment-827815038

Adding the query solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [SqliteConnectOptions](https://docs.rs/sqlx-sqlite/0.7.1/sqlx_sqlite/struct.SqliteConnectOptions.html) in conjunction with [Pool::connect_with](https://docs.rs/sqlx-core/0.7.1/sqlx_core/pool/struct.Pool.html) with newer versions of sqlx.

```rust
use sqlx::{sqlite::SqliteConnectOptions, Error, SqlitePool};
use std::{future::Future, path::Path};

async fn connect(filename: impl AsRef<Path>) -> impl Future<Output = Result<SqlitePool, Error>> {
    let options = SqliteConnectOptions::new()
        .filename(filename)
        .create_if_missing(true);

    SqlitePool::connect_with(&options)
}
```

`SqliteConnectOptions` is very flexible and supports many useful options such as loading extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Standard practice is to set your DATABASE_URL

```
sqlx db create
```

then run

```
sqlx migrate run
```